# TornadoFX: Layout of listview shifts if content is modified

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, tornadofx

I have a `ListView` inside of a TornadoFX form builder field that can be added to and removed from by some buttons off to the side. However whenever the contents of the list is modified from the buttons, the list moves vertically downwards. The height of the `ListView` remains the same, but it's almost as if there is padding being generated along the top whenever the content length is modified. The height change is then reset as soon as there is some change in focus, either by clicking on another component in the view, or by unfocussing and refocussing the window.

I've tried to limit the ability for this to happen by enforcing a max height, both on the form field and on the `ListView` itself, but neither worked.

Using listeners to print out all the values I could think of that would result in this change, I found that the "bounds in Parent" were changing, adding a value of 17 to both the minY and maxY values. I've not been able to determine where this value of 17 comes from.

The current code for the view is here: https://pastebin.com/6qFVvxvP

I also have some images to help visualize what the problem is:

Before removing content:

[image: Before removing content]

After removing content:

[image: After removing content]